# Who are all the other ‘Iron Men’ in the Iron Man 3 trailer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, marvel, iron-man-3

It looks like there are about fifty Iron Men in the new Iron Man Movie: **Iron Man 3**.

Who are all these Iron Men? Is Pepper Potts one of them? Or is it all The Avengers, but wearing Iron Man costumes?

Here's a snapshot from the [international trailer](http://io9.com/5988865/get-a-tad-more-tony-stark-in-the-iron-man-3-international-trailer):

[image: a bunch of iron mans]

Comment: Perhaps among them is the people who look like they're being fitted with suits at [1:51](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue43ALt_s-Y#t=1m50s)?

Comment: @Izkata Heh, I assumed they were getting injected with an Extremis dose.

Comment: it's a trailer - i'm assuming that the identities will be revealed in the full movie when it is released

Comment: I'm with HorusKol on this one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an allusion to the [Argonauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_armor#Argonauts)[image: Argonauts Armors]

As well as this image by Oliver Coipel

[image: Armors] where Tony demonstrates his ability to control several armors at once using tech similar to the NTU-Telepresence armor.

You can see in this still shot he is wearing what I believe is a Telepresence headset.

[image: Teleprescense]

Comment: Yes this must be it. The trailer shows the fat one, second from the left in your first picture.

Answer (score 8):

Elsewhere in that same trailer, we see a flying Iron Man suit [that Tony jumps into](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue43ALt_s-Y#t=2m02s).  The back of the suit is open, and he leaps into it, then takes over.  This suggests that these suits may be remote controlled, so it's likely that most of them are empty in that image.

It's unlikely that if there are pilots in the suits that they would be Avengers, as Kevin Feige, Marvel Studios President [stated in an interview](http://www.slashfilm.com/kevin-feige-says-iron-man-3-will-explain-why-tony-stark-doesnt-call-the-avengers/):

> *Journalist:* After cell phones came out horror directors had to come up with elaborate ways to explain why people wouldn’t call someone on a cell phone for help, now that all The Avengers know each other do you have to come up with excuses for why Tony Stark wouldn’t reach out when he needs a hand?
>
> *Feige:* It’s a good question, and it’s sort of half and half. I am betting that like the comics you don’t have to keep – if you are reading a standalone “Iron Man” comic, they don’t spend every page explaining where every other Marvel hero is. The audience kind of accepts that there are times when they’re on their own and there are times when they are together. I’m betting that movie audiences will feel the same way. That being said, there is a little bit of lip service here and there to that. There is also just the very nature of Tony wants to, once he barely survives that house attack you saw today, and even you saw it in the message he left for Pepper, he’s basically saying “I’m going off the grid to try to figure something out.”

It's currently unknown who is controlling them remotely (Tony, JARVIS, a villain, etc.), as the film is not yet released.  It's likely that Tony is doing so, as [in a previous trailer](http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/marvel/ironman3/) (Trailer 1 at 0:27) we see him wearing a device on his head and remotely guiding components of a new Iron Man armor onto himself.  In addition, it's been [discussed in interviews](http://collider.com/iron-man-3-extremis-shane-black-poster/) that the movie will adapt the Extremis storyline.  In that storyline, Tony gets some augmentations to himself, which allows him to remotely guide and control Iron Man suits.

Comment: That's basically a non-answer. Just because the film hasn't been released doesn't mean nobody knows what happens in it, or at least some specifics of the plot.

Comment: @user973810 Actually that's pretty much exactly what the issue is with unreleased movies, we don't know what happens in it.  Anyway, see my edit.  I was able to at least address your 'are these the Avengers?' question.

Comment: Until the film is finished being edited, nobody (except the director and editor/s) knows exactly what is happening. Everything is subject to change at pretty much any time. Things written or even filmed are never guaranteed to be in the final version. Hell, even things shown in the trailers are cut from the movie (see The Amazing Spider-Man for a great example of this).

Comment: Conversely, with something as major as 50 Iron Men flying through the trailer, it's safe to assume that it's not going to be cut from the movie, and that hundreds of people who have worked on the movie know the plot motivation.

Comment: @user973810 People sworn to secrecy who know something isn't a good rebuttal to "it's not released, so we don't know what's happens in it."

Comment: And yet major details can be changed at the very last minute. Look at how *nobody* except for Lucas and James Earl Jones knew about Vader and Luke's relationship until the movie was released - including the actors in the scene.

Comment: I can see it now. "Thor, take the one on the left." "Can I bring my hammer?" "NO. Cpt. Take the one on the right, and... no shield this time, you are the shield. And Bruce, sorry, I don't have a suit that can get 10 times larger on demand. You'll have to sit this one out."

Comment: @phantom42: http://www.slashfilm.com/david-prowse-ruin-the-empire-strikes-back-years-release/

Comment: Yes, I've read that. Pretty much everyone's take is that Prowse was either joking or speculating - much like what has to be done to answer this question fully right now.

Answer (score 6):

Spoiler:

> They are remotely controlled by him: Operation "House Party"

The movie came out last week in japan (4/26/2013)

Comment: Although there’s quite a lot of artificial intelligence involved as well.

Answer (score 4):

Armors in the film were mark 25 striker mark 33 silver centurion mark 38 igor mark42 mark 17 heartbreaker mark 40 shotgun mark 39 starboost mark 35 red snapper mark 37 hammerhead.. These are the armors Stark built in the film.

Answer (score 4):

The suits were all (almost all) unmanned, and controlled remotely by JARVIS as part of operation "House Party".

They are all the various prototype and production suits Tony had built.

> During the battle in which they participated, Tony jumped from suit to suit, as needed, which is why I say "almost all" are unmanned.

Answer (score 2):

We've had an example of someone else wearing Iron Man Armour in War Machine, if a big enough threat makes it's self apparent there is no reason Tony couldn't have a military unit suited up in a set of Iron Man suits.

About 1:50 in [this trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue43ALt_s-Y) we see what looks like people being measured for suits? That could hint at an army of Iron Men?

Although the conversation between Tony and Rhodes:

"We do need backup"

"That's Your department"

And

"There's my boys"

Imply that it might not be military, and might be as other have suggested remotely controlled, or AI controlled Iron Men.

There is precedent for this, the suits that Vanko puts together in Iron Man 2 are remotely controlled.

Comment: I believe Tony uses the term "Boys" to mean robots.  He refers to the robots in his house as "Boys" on several occasions.

Comment: The scene in the trailer you're talking about appears to be of soldiers getting ready to take the Extremis serum. If you look closely at this [screen capture](http://i.imgur.com/APW5X7o.png) you'll see Aldrich Killian, the inventor of the serum, standing in the room (middle).

Answer (score -2):

the suits are being controlled by Jarvis under Tony's control.

Comment: Although you're not wrong, this answer does little more than repeat what you can see in earlier, better referenced answers.